# ScrollTop - jQuery does not scroll

Tags: jquery, scrolltop

I've got this code:

http://jsfiddle.net/goodghost/MEr3a/

```
$(function() {

 var myWidth = $(".container").width();
 var myHeight = $(window).height();
 console.log(myHeight);
 var myShift = (1920 - myWidth)/2;

 $(".container").scrollLeft(myShift);


 //small window
 $(".dragMe").css({"left":myShift/10+"px", "width":(myWidth)/10+"px", "height":myHeight/10+"px"});
 $(".dragMe").draggable({
            addClasses: false, 
            containment: "parent",
            drag: function(event, ui) { 
              var offset = $(this).offset();
              var xPos = offset.left;
              var yPos = offset.top;
              console.log(yPos);
              $(".container").scrollLeft(xPos*10);
              $(".container").scrollTop(yPos*10+"px");
            }
 });
});
```

What I want to achieve is to scroll in every direction the image inside .container triggered by movement of the semi transparent div with class dragMe. Anyone know why it's working only with left and right, but not top, bottom?

Comment: Compare your calls to `scrollLeft()` and `scrollTop()`. Can you see the issue? *(Hint: both these methods take numbers, not strings.)*

Comment: this doesn't do the job, that's why I've put it there, even if I put $(".container").scrollTop(yPos*10); this also doesn't work

Comment: jQuery's scrolltop only accepts integers, not strings

Comment: I've updated the code in jsFiddle and even I've given additional function parseInt() with the value I get but this does not work

Comment: the problem is that `.container` has no `y scroll`. The scrollbar you see is from `body`. It's because the height is the same as body so no scrollbar is needed, only body needs one as you can see here http://jsfiddle.net/Spokey/MEr3a/7/. You may need change some stuff around

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you will not be able to use `$('.container').scrollTop` if you allow the div to grow 100% in height. you need to set a width and height for `.container` and it will work like a charm.

JsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/MEr3a/9/

Answer (score 1):

Your container can't scroll because it has no way to scroll.

When you look at your example, the vertical scroll bar belong to the window, but not to your container. You can try this :

```
$(window).scrollTop(yPos * 10);
```

(But the `* 10` is not the good value i think)

Comment: `$(window).scrollTop` will scroll the thumbnail too and the user will not be able to drag inside the thumbnail.

Comment: I know. The html structure should be modified to do the right thing. But i just pointed the fact that, at the moment, the container can't scroll.